# The rate at which fCM sends messages to topics is much lower than sending messages to devices

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I subscribed 1.5 million users to topic TEST. I sent a message to TEST with a reach rate of only 10% to 20%. If I send it alone to 1.5 million users, the arrival rate will reach 40% to 60%. We think 40% ~ 60% are reasonable. Does FCM have any restrictions on the amount of delivery for topic messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of devices that can subscribe to a topic. tThe only difference between using a topic and directly sending to the device IDs should be that topic delivery takes slightly longer due to the fan-out process.

As long as the devices have subscribed to the topics with their latest tokens/instance IDs, the delivery rates should be the same.

If this is not the case, it would be great if you can give clear steps to reproduce in the question. But I get that this may not be possible if the problem only happens at >1M registrations. In that case I recommend [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.